# Postgres SQL Insert Command combined with WHERE

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

I thought this would be easy, but I can't make it work:

```
Table=(int,int,text)

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from database_data ncd inner join players p on p.player_id = ncd.player_id where p.playername ='Name1', conn);

string _data = (String)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

now I got the data....NOW I just wanna write it back...but...

```
NpgsqlCommand command2 = new NpgsqlCommand("Update database_data ncd inner join players p on p.player_id = ncd.player_id where p.playername ='Name2' + "'", conn);
command2.Parameters.Add(?????)
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I only managed to update the whole row.

```
NpgsqlCommand command2 = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into database_data values(1,2222,3333)", conn);
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

This works nicely, but I cannot combine it with the join and where.

If join doesn't work, I can simply work with `where player_id=x`
and get the `player_id` somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

From my best knowledge update statement in pqsql should look like

```
update <table> set field1=value1, field2=value2 .... from FROM_CLAUSE WHERE WHERE_CLAUSE
```

But in your piece of code your statement did not match with this template. So, could you please tell more precisely what you want to do with data?

Comment: havn't checked the answers yet....my intent is to write a new value into the field..I see I messed up the copy and paste in the example...I will fix that first

Comment: So I edited the question...the first Readstuff works...I just wanna do the same and write the data back....but when I add VALUE into the statement it doesn't work ....so again FIRST STRING works!!

Comment: "update database_data set data='teeeest' where player_id=17"   this one works so far.....thx for the set....

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is going to fail in Postgres unless you have a table called `ncd.data`:

```
Update ncd.data 
    from data ncd inner join
         players p
         on p.player_id = ncd.player_id
    where p.playername ='Name2' + "'";
```

I am guessing your intention is:

```
Update data ncd
    from players p
    where p.player_id = ncd.player_id and
          p.playername ='Name2' + "'";
```

Comment: yes I have a table database_data(edited it for better understanding) ...as said my first example works.... "update database_data set data='teeeest' where player_id=17"...this one works too....now I try and combine it with:     ncd inner join players p on p.player_id = ncd.player_id where p.playername ='Name1'        so I don't need to get the id in a seperate statement

Comment: just to make clear: this one work for reading:   select * from database_data ncd inner join players p on p.player_id = ncd.player_id where p.playername ='Name1'

Comment: I just used two statements....  ID=select player_id from players where playername='Name'      update database_data set data = '45645' where player_id =ID

Comment: @Tetragrammaton . . . Are you saying that the second query in this answer did not work?  If so, I'll just delete the answer.

Comment: yes.....I JUST need to combine these two...just for curiosity:                   ++ID=select player_id from players where playername='Name'++                         ++update database_data set data = '45645' where player_id =ID++                       these two work in 2 "lines"...